# If you only have an Ethernet MAC without higher layer, what happens if packet is lost?

Tags: networking

Does an Ethernet MAC have a built in ack/retransmit scheme or is this the job of a higher layer of network protocol?

In other words, if you have only the Mac layer and an Ethernet packet is lost ... what happens without the higher layers?

I was just curious if you could take a 40G full duplex MAC, reverse the phy transmits lanes into receive lanes and get a half duplex that runs 80G and only receives packets...  the problem here is if Ethernet sends any kind of ack at Mac or phy levels...

It seems like it would work if you had UDP riding on top of Mac... and only needs to transmit packets from source to destination...

Comment: The MAC is responsible for backing off and re-sending in the case of a collision  in half-duplex but otherwise does not re-send.

Comment: It's the role of higher levers to manage retransmissions. For example TCP/IP.

Answer (score 2):

The MAC layer doesn’t guarantee delivery. Some simpler layers on top of it (like UDP) don’t either. TCP/IP does.

Comment: TCP does. IP does not.

Comment: Also TCP does not guarantee delivery. If the network is awfully overloaded and very high percentage of packets are lost, it may fail to deliver too. TCP is a large abstraction, and as with all such things, it [leaks](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/).

Answer (score 2):

> I was just curious if you could take a 40G full duplex MAC, reverse the phy transmits lanes into receive lanes

No. A transmitter is a transmitter and not a receiver. If you need a faster receiver, you'll have to buy a receiver for a faster standard or channel-bond one.

> and get a half duplex that runs 80G and only receives packets.

Thus, the above being physically impossible, no.

> the problem here is if Ethernet sends any kind of ack at Mac or phy levels.

You can maybe convince the firmware of your NIC and your OS to not require the other end to signal a carrier, but it still doesn't give you your 80 GBit link, because you'll need a different card and receiver, physically, on both ends of your link, which doesn't exist.

> In other words, if you have only the Mac layer and an Ethernet packet is lost ... what happens without the higher layers?

The packet stays lost.

Also, without the higher layers, your ethernet link really isn't that useful.

Imagine this: you've actually built an 80 Gbit/s link. Your link has a bit error rate of 10⁻¹⁴ after IEEE 802.3-2015 Clause 74 error decoding (just throwing in really good numbers for now). That means that you have one broken packet every couple of minutes – now, in a system with higher layers, no problem, can remedy that through retransmission, but without, huh. What to do? Live with the broken packet? That might work, but it really requires you to think about what your application really needs.